# Is a micrometer meter cached when I create an instance?

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

What happens under the hood when I create a Micrometer Counter or Timer? Is it cached? If it is cached could I use the builder anytime and add tags dinamically?

```
Counter counter = Counter
    .builder("instance_name")
    .description("bla bla...")
    .tags("tag_name", "tag_value")
    .register(registry);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you man by cached. Meters in Micrometer are created from and held in a MeterRegistry. Also, a meter is uniquely identified by its combination of name and tags so if you request a meter with the same name and tags, you should get back the same instance:

```
Counter counter1 = Counter
        .builder("instance_name")
        .description("bla bla...")
        .tags("tag_name", "tag_value")
        .register(registry);

Counter counter2 = Counter
        .builder("instance_name")
        .description("bla bla...")
        .tags("tag_name", "tag_value")
        .register(registry);

System.out.println(counter1 == counter2); // should print true
```

You can do this any time and add tags dynamically (see: [`WebMvcMetricsFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/e7c1c8937d9b9691962209c5585893935c566634/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsFilter.java#L151)), the only thing you need to pay attention is calling register at the end.